# Exporting Sales Orders to Sage

Tags: mysql, .net

I am exporting Sales orders to Sage 2012 by doing inserts into the MySQL tables `tsalorder` and `tsoline`. I am following some code from another system that is currently in place and works correctly.

The sales orders show up correctly along with the line items. What's not working is that items from the export are taxed at a 7% GST rate and items that are added manually are taxed at the correct 5% rate. I am not writing records to the `tsolinet` table at the moment. Doing so didnt seem to make a difference. The tax codes are setup correctly. The test Sage database is a backup and restore of the production system.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple revisions of the tax code I was using. Setting the right revision value corrected the problem.